# Java API to generate Excel

Tags: java, excel, export-to-excel

What is the best Java API to generate excel sheets (compatible with lateset Excel) including formulas? Is there more than POI and JXL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been switching between POI and JXL a few times. Both work just fine. The reason I moved away from POI in the past was because the POI development went idled. That said, I have switched back to POI now that the development is active again. One thing I like about POI is it [handles XLSX format](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

There is also this: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ , but POI is pretty much the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI I have used in one of the projects. It worked well for me.

http://poi.apache.org/

Supports many MS Office formats.